# Java - Finding even numbers and the percent of them within an array

Tags: java

This is the question that I need to figure out:

Write a method called percentEven that accepts an array of integers as a parameter and returns the percentage of even numbers in the array as a real number. For example, if the array stores the elements [6, 2, 9, 11, 3] then your method should return 40.0. If the array contains no even elements or no elements at all, return 0.0.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Change {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Let's find the range.");
    System.out.println("Enter five numbers to find the range.");

    int num = console.nextInt();
    int[] list = new int[num];

    System.out.println("The numbers you entered are: " + list.length); 
    System.out.println();

    percentEven(list);

    }

    public static void percentEven(int[] num){

        int percent = 0;
        int even = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            if(num[i] % 2 == 0){
            even++;
            }

        }  

      percent = (even / num.length) *100;

        System.out.println("The percent of even numbers is: " + percent);      
    }


}
```

When I run it, I get 100 as the percent.

Comment: `returns the percentage of even numbers in the array as a real number.` There is no such thing as a `real` number in terms of a computer.

Comment: Is your list.length printing as expected?  you aren't populating your `list` array in a loop, so it looks like you're just overwriting the value each time

Comment: My list prints properly, but I'm losing my list somewhere after that. I tried adding int[] list = new int [5]. This did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Two issues here:

Cast one of them to a double or float.

```
percent = (even / (double) num.length) *100;
```

The other issue is that you never assign the numbers any value, so they are all 0. `0 % 2` is equal to 0, so the list is, by definition, 100% even.

---

You should also have a base case in the method when `nums == {}`, which would return 0.0 as the assignment states.

Comment: I was thinking this same thing, but if it's a problem due to integer math truncation, it should be giving 0%, not 100%. Right?

Comment: @DaoWen I believe I addressed that concern appropriately now. He never assigned values to those numbers, they are all 0 and therefore all even.

Comment: What's really happening is even / num.length < 1 (0.?????)  times that by 100, so in reality its 0*100

Comment: Since even / num are both ints, they only get the Int value of the double

Comment: It's giving 100% because all the numbers are zero.  If there were any odd numbers at all, it would give 0% because of the integer division.

Comment: I would have liked to upvote this answer three times, because it correctly addresses ALL THREE problems with the code.

Comment: Ah, I see now. He's not actually initializing the `list`. In either case, I agree he needed to do floating-point math—I was just confused why he'd get 100% instead of 0%. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by assigning the numbers to a value.

Comment: @user3019459 `int[] list = new int[num];` since this is a field, all of these values will be pre-initialized to `0`. which is even.

Answer (score 2):

There are three major problems in your code:

1. You are reading only ONE integer, not five
2. You use this single integer to define the LENGTH of the array, not the content (so you don't put the integer into the array. So the array contains only zeroes, which means that all of them are even.
3. You are doing wrong integer arithmetic (as Obicere already stated in his answer). But this doesn't have any effect, as all elements of the array are even, so the result will be 100 in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. But you are initializing and storing the array wrong way. Do this

```
int num = console.nextInt();
int[] list = new int[num];
System.out.println("Enter " + num + " numbers");
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    list[i] = console.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("The numbers you entered are: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(list)); 
System.out.println();
```

and also do as other suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
percent = even * 100 / num.length;
```

Changing the order of the operations will make the integer division business work in your favour - you'll get a value rounded down to the next lowest percentage, rather than rounded down to zero.

Also fix the problem with all the numbers being zero by reading them from the keyboard, as in tintinmj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class percentEvenClass
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] list = {6, 2, 9, 11, 3};
    int percentEven_Result = percentEven(list);
    System.out.println(percentEven_Result);
  }
  public static int percentEven(int[] list){

    int count = 0;
    int percent = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

        if (list[i] % 2 == 0){
            count++;
        }
        percent = (count * 100)/ list.length;

 }
  return percent;
```

}

}